# KeyError: "None of [Index(['2019-06-06', '2019-06-10'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]

Tags: pandas

Below gives error `KeyError: "None of [Index(['2019-06-06', '2019-06-10'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"` what's the problem?

```
test_data = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6], index=['20190606','20190610','20190708','20190805','20190909','20190930'])
test_data.index=pd.to_datetime(test_data.index)

print(test_data.loc[['2019-06-06','2019-06-10']])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no match, because pandas cannot by default convert list of datetimes to datetimes, so is necessary converting first:

```
print(test_data.loc[pd.to_datetime(['2019-06-06','2019-06-10'])])
2019-06-06    1
2019-06-10    2
dtype: int64
```